# Trouble understanding double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the following double integral that intakes two functions:

$$F_{W}\left ( w \right ) = \int_{0}^{w}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^{2}-h^{2}}}f_{Z}\left ( z \right )f_{X}\left ( x \right ) \,dz\,dx \ \ \mathrm{for } \ 0\leq w< H$$

Where the functions $f_{X}\left ( x \right )$ and $f_{Z}\left ( z \right )$ are given by:

$$f_{X}\left ( x \right )= \frac{1}{H}$$

$$f_{Z}\left ( z \right )= \frac{2z}{R^2}$$

Based on [this paper by Sharma et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8671460) (Lemma 1 in Appendix), the resulting integral is:

$$F_{W}\left ( w \right ) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{w^3}{R^2H}  \ \ \mathrm{for } \ 0\leq w< H$$

I don't get this answer, and I have tried looking up at the "
[Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/%7Esvincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf)" but I do not get how it was done. Any help or hints on this *blackbox* would be highly appreciated, cause I've been trying for days to understand this part of the paper but it's impossible.

Comment: is the upper limit of the inner integral $\sqrt{w^2-H^2}$?

Comment: What's a "blackbox"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 . It is what I was thinking about. But it does not seem to make sense;

Comment: Do you not know what a double integral is?

Comment: my bad i forgot that $w < H$

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I think you mean $\sqrt{H^2 - w^2}$.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget thx that's it.  $h$ isn't defined in this question.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget it is a term used to define something that you do not know how it works inside. It is an expression, another way of saying "I gave it this input but I don't know why it gave this output".

Comment: Why are you integrating to $\sqrt{w^2-h^2}$?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget yes I know, but I do not understand this specific one

Comment: have you tried WolframAlpha?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget the paper I have attached suggests to integrate it that way. Theoretically, $w$ represents the hypotenuse of a triangle, $z$ its length, and $h$ its height.

Comment: What about WolframAlpha?

Comment: Also, did you make a mistake, because you mean $h < w$?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget yes I have tried Wolfram Alpha, and it give the same result as me doing it manually. But I do not know how it was achieved in this paper.

Comment: Can't you compute this as an iterated integral?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118378/discussion-between-rf-s-and-new-qopenglwidget).

Comment: It has to be $\int_{0}^{w}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^2-x^2}}  \frac{2z} {H R^2} \ dz \ dx$. Pls check otherwise $z$ and $x$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @MathLover. They are related as follows: $w^2 = z^2 + h^2$ (should have said it earlier, my bad)

Comment: Yes then integral should read $dz \ dh$ and not $dz \ dx$ or you write $w^2 = z^2 + x^2$ and the integral reads $dz \ dx$. I hope it explains.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: try this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.02937.pdf

Comment: I can only get \begin{align}
F_{W}\left ( w \right ) &= \int_{0}^{w}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^{2}-h^{2}}}f_{Z}\left ( z \right )f_{X}\left ( x \right ) \,dz\,dx \ \ \mathrm{for } \ 0\leq w< H, 0 \le h \le H \\
&= \int_0^w \int_0^{\sqrt{w^{2}-h^{2}}} \frac{2z}{R^2} \, \frac1H \, dz \, dx \\
&= \int_0^w \frac{1}{R^2 H} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{\left(\sqrt{w^{2}-h^{2}}\right)^2}{2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{(w^2 - h^2) w}{R^2 H}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the commentators has already mentioned, it seems to be that $h = x$, hence the equation would be written as:

$$F_{W}\left ( w \right ) = \int_{0}^{w}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^{2}-x^{2}}}f_{Z}\left ( z \right )f_{X}\left ( x \right ) \,dz\,dx \ \ \mathrm{for } \ 0\leq w< H$$

I have checked the equation with the rest of the integrals that the paper presents and it is a valid result.