# Integral from paper doesn't make sense

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Based on [this paper by Sharma et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8671460) [[link to pdf]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12hzC8P-FfFfuq8ybIl0wj4oAecjsmBKa/view?usp=sharing)(Lemma 1 in Appendix), the following integrals have the following results:

$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^{2}- R^{2}}}\int_{0}^{R}\left [ \frac{2z}{HR^2} \right] \,dz\,dx = - \frac{2}{3}\frac{(w^{2}- R^{2})^\frac{3}{2}}{HR^2} \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Eq.} 1$$

$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^{2}- R^{2}}}\int_{0}^{R}\left [ \frac{12xz}{H^2R^2} - \frac{12x^2z}{H^3R^2} \right] \,dz\,dx = - \frac{3}{2}\frac{(w^{2}- R^{2})^2}{H^2R^2} + \frac{4}{5}\frac{(w^{2}- R^{2})^\frac{5}{2}}{H^3R^2}  \ \ \ \ \ \mathrm{Eq.} 2$$

Where $R$ and $H$ are constants (non-zero positive), and $w$, $z$ and $x$ variables which are related through $w^2 = x^2 + z^2$.

**If you compute the integrals you can see that the answer that we get is not the same.** The final answer of the integral is correct. But the incorrect part is the left-hand side, more precisely (my suggestion), the limits of the integrals. I have tried the following:

$$ \int_{0}^{\sqrt{w^{2}- R^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2 - (w^{2}- R^{2})}}\left [ ... \right] \,dz\,dx $$

It does work for Eq. 1 but not for Eq. 2.

As a background, I have found quite a few mistakes on this paper, one of them [being this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982579/trouble-understanding-double-integral/4065959#4065959), which was solved by basically changing the limits of the integral. There were other cases too in which other integrals had their limits mixed up e.g. limits of $dx$ was swapped with limits of $dz$. Any hint, guidance or method of tries would be highly appreciated (been stuck for days)!

Edit: Mistaken power

Edit 2: PDF file of paper included

Comment: No commercial link, please.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What commercial link? Do you mean the IEEE paper or the related question link? Please let me know

Comment: IEEE of course.

Comment: You have to calculate the integrals of $1,x,z^2$. It does not get any harder. Where is the problem?

Comment: @vitamind The problem is that I get $\frac{2(w^{2}- R^{2})^\frac{1}{2}}{H}$ for Eq. 1 if I compute it the way the paper says it. I need to know what limits are used that yield those results, but no luck after several tries.